# How to create Grid view webpart using Visual Studio or code

Tags: gridview

I need a Grid View Webpart to display multiple rows and columns like an Excel range of columns​. i.e. Users are able to see different columns for different rows. Is it possible to do it via Visual Studio or Coding?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What about datasheet view? Also, I'm assuming you're not looking for a normal SPGridView? Can you explain more what you're trying to do?

Comment: The data in a list can be copied in excel. However, I want to show these items as grid in some way (through some webpart or view style or something).

Comment: If you want to copy the data into excel, wouldn't you just provide an "export" feature so they could download an excel file with the data already in it?